# Is it possible to set the a variable group scope using DevOps CLI or via REST

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-cli2

I am able to add/modify DevOps release definitions through a combination of CLI and CLI REST methods.  The release definition object does not include (as far as I can tell) a property that controls the variable group scope.  The release definition itself takes an array of variable group ID's but there is also the scope of the variable group within the context of the release definition. Where is that?

Is there support to access the variable group scope property in the CLI or CLI REST interface?  The image below shows the interface from the portal in azure.  Selecting the ellipses (...) you can "change scope" where a list of stages is displayed. You than save and then save the release definition.
[image]

I captured fiddler output but the body post was huge and not very helpful, I didn't see anything related to a list of scopes. but obviously this can be done. I'm just not sure about doing so via CLI or REST.

Edit:  Here is a view of the script.  There is no "scope", which should contain a list of environment names, anywhere in the release definition that I can see.  Each environment name (aka stage) contains a number of variable groups associated with each environment.

```
$sourcedefinition = getreleasedefinitionrequestwithpat $reldefid $personalAccesstoken $org $project | select -Last 1

Write-Host "Root VariableGroups: " $sourcedefinition.variableGroups

$result = @()
#search each stage in the pipeline
foreach($item in $sourcedefinition.environments)
{    
  Write-Host ""
  Write-Host "environment name: "$item.name   
  Write-Host "environment variable groups: "$item.variableGroups
}
```

To help clarify, the scope I seek cannot be in the environments collection as this is specific to each element (stage).  The scope is set at the release definition level for a given variable group (again refer to the image).

Answer (score 0):

I use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get the Definitions of my release and find that the values of `variableGroups` in **ReleaseDefinition** and in **ReleaseDefinitionEnvironment** are different when the scopes are different.

Then I think if we want to change the scope via REST API, we just need to change the `variableGroups` and update the Definitions. We can use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to update the Definitions.

**Edit:**
For example, I want to change my scope from **Release to Stage**, I use the API like below:

```
PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.1-preview.4
```

**Request Body:** (I get this from the first Get Definitions API Response Body and make some changes to use it)

```
{
   "source":"userInterface",
   "revision":6,
   ...
   "lastRelease": {
       "id": 1,
       ...
   },
   ...
   "variables":{          
   },
   "variableGroups":[],
   "environments":[
      {
         "name": "Stage 1",
         ...
         "variables":{                
         },
         "variableGroups":[ 
             4               
         ],
         ...
      }
    ],
  ...
}
```

**Note:**

1. Please use your own newer `revision`.
2. The `id` value in `lastRelease` is your release definitionId.
3. Specify the stage name in `environments` `name`.
4. The `variableGroups` value in `environments` is the id of the variable group you want to change scope.

Comment: I edited my OP to show the script where release definition can be pulled and output the variable groups associated with each environment.  This is not my question.  I'm trying to access the "scope" of the variable group at the release definition level (see the image in my OP).  If you have additional information about how to change this, please let me know.

Comment: @user2503078 Do you want ot change the scope from Release to Stage for one variable group? If so, you can set the variable group id in `environments variableGroups`. Please see my edit.